# RollupError: Could not resolve "./App.jsx" from "src/index.jsx"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, render, github-pages

I am trying to host my vite react app on Render as a static webpage but I am facing below issues. Not sure why I see this. In my local I can build and my application is up and running on localhost.

Why this is happening? I am trying to learn coding.

```
Nov 13 11:50:04 AM  Could not resolve "./App.jsx" from "src/index.jsx"
Nov 13 11:50:04 AM  file: /opt/render/project/src/SWE_Portfolio/src/index.jsx
Nov 13 11:50:04 AM  error during build:
Nov 13 11:50:04 AM  RollupError: Could not resolve "./App.jsx" from "src/index.jsx"
Nov 13 11:50:04 AM      at error (file:///opt/render/project/src/SWE_Portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
```

I created react app using vite initially and try to host it and was seeing error. After that I tried create react app and deployed and saw the same error. But in local my code works fine without any error. Finally I tried checking the structure of my code and that looks fine. I tried hosting as gh pages, same blank page.

Structure of my React app

[image]

Comment: can You provide vite.configs and index.jsx code ?

Comment: Did you follow this guide? https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#render